# Open project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I received an java project, and I need to open it in Eclipse.
I have a folder with the follow structure :

```
  Project :
           .classpath
           .project
           .settings
            src
            build 
            WebContent:
                      WEB-INF
```

I put it in the workspace directory but the eclipse does not show me the project.
I have open the .classpath file and i see a lot of  for example :

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/J2EE/glassfishv3/glassfish/modules/javax.servlet.jar"/><classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/J2EE/glassfishv3"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Mail/mail.jar"/>
```

**I do not have the last three path in my machine .**
So my question is what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to put the project folder inside the Eclipse workspace, it won't be picked up that way.

The recommended way of importing an Eclipse project is to go through the *File > Import... > General > Existing projects into workspace...* wizard. Don't copy the project folder into the workspace, point to its original location instead; if you select the *Copy projects into workspace* checkbox, the imported project will be automatically copied into your workspace.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers, i am importing the project File > Import... > General > Existing projects into workspace... wizard. but at 91% is asking me for credentials : user and password. I try to see what is happening in the log file , but nothing appears. Anyone have a clue ? Probably is some path that is pointing to something in a remote location but where i can find it ?

Thanks in advance Best regards

Comment: Is there any other text on the username/password dialog? It might be trying to connect to a version control server (e.g. SVN, CVS, etc), but since this looks like a web project it might even be the remote server, where the project is configured to be deployed.
What happens if you don't supply a username and password?

Comment: I am working behind a VPN, and a proxy. When i go to the eclipse network configurations , the proxy entries are fullfil with the properties configured in internet explorer.I already tested this import in my home , and it work. So what could i do to work behind this proxy ? I see in the log the following message
`System property http.proxyHost is set to internetgept.oil.galpenergia.corp but should not be set.`

Comment: @tt0686 I'm afraid I can't help you with the proxy issue, I never had to deal with that.

Answer (score 2):

There's an Import command on the file menu.

You shouldn't manually put the project in your workspace folder; Eclipse will copy it there when you import it.

Comment: It works just fine if you put it manually into the workspace folder and then import it from the file menu. Eclipse will do everything but the copying step.

Comment: you don't even have to explicitly import it, see my answer

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers, i am importing the project File > Import... > General > Existing projects into workspace... wizard. but at 91% is asking me for credentials : user and password. I try to see what is happening in the log file , but nothing appears. Anyone have a clue ? Probably is some path that is pointing to something in a remote location but where i can find it ?

Thanks in advance Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you already copied it into the worskpace folder, there's no need to import.

Just do the following:

File -> new -> project -> dynamic web  project -> Put the name of the project folder.

Eclipse will autodetect existing project setup and put it in workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You should create folder, eg. `MyWorkspace`, place your eclipse project in it. Then fire up eclipse, when It'll ask for your workspace folder, enter your `MyWorkspace` full path (use browse button). Then eclipse will begin starting. After its loading will complete, select 'Add' -> new Project, then in the 'new Project' window enter as a project name, name of the project you've received, at the moment when you completely type your project name, all fields will became grayed, this means that your existing project will be used, press next, then complete your project set-up. Cheers.